# ggplot error using rmarkdown - object ´percent´ not found

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

So I have been making this scatterplot using ggplot in R. 
By using this code as listed below in a regular r script in RStudio I am able to produce the plot that I want to without any errors.

The problem is when I am trying to use the same code in a chunk using rmarkdown to knit to PDF.
I get an error saying: **Error in check_breaks_labels(breaks, labels): object `percent` not found.**

Any suggestions? Hope the reproducable example is ok.

```
library(tidyquant)
library(timetk)
library(ggplot2)

SPY <- tq_get("SPY", from = '2010-01-01',
                  to = "2020-04-04",
                  get = "stock.prices")

FXI <- tq_get("FXI", from = '2010-01-01',
              to = "2020-04-04",
              get = "stock.prices")

QQQ <- tq_get("QQQ", from = '2010-01-01',
              to = "2020-04-04",
              get = "stock.prices")


SPY_monthly_returns <- SPY %>%
  tq_transmute(select = adjusted,
               mutate_fun = periodReturn,
               period = "monthly",      
               col_rename = "SPY_ret")

FXI_monthly_returns <- FXI %>%
  tq_transmute(select = adjusted,
               mutate_fun = periodReturn,
               period = "monthly",      
               col_rename = "FXI_ret")

QQQ_monthly_returns <- QQQ %>%
  tq_transmute(select = adjusted,
               mutate_fun = periodReturn,
               period = "monthly",      
               col_rename = "QQQ_ret")

SPY_monthly_mean_ret <- SPY_monthly_returns %>%
  select(SPY_ret) %>%
  .[[1]] %>%
  mean(na.rm = TRUE)


FXI_monthly_mean_ret <- FXI_monthly_returns %>%
  select(FXI_ret) %>%
  .[[1]] %>%
  mean(na.rm = TRUE)


QQQ_monthly_mean_ret <- QQQ_monthly_returns %>%
  select(QQQ_ret) %>%
  .[[1]] %>%
  mean(na.rm = TRUE)

SPY_monthly_sd_ret <- SPY_monthly_returns %>%
  select(SPY_ret) %>%
  .[[1]] %>%
  sd()

FXI_monthly_sd_ret <- FXI_monthly_returns %>%
  select(FXI_ret) %>%
  .[[1]] %>%
  sd()

QQQ_monthly_sd_ret <- QQQ_monthly_returns %>%
  select(QQQ_ret) %>%
  .[[1]] %>%
  sd()



d <- data.frame(meanret = c(SPY_monthly_mean_ret,FXI_monthly_mean_ret,QQQ_monthly_mean_ret), sd = c(SPY_monthly_sd_ret,FXI_monthly_sd_ret,QQQ_monthly_sd_ret), names = c("SPY","FXI","QQQ"))

ggplot(d, aes(sd,meanret, color= ticker)) + 
geom_point(size=1) + geom_text(aes(label=names)) + 
ggtitle("Monthly Risk-Return Plot") + xlab("Volatility") +
ylab("Mean Return") + theme_bw() +
scale_y_continuous(label = percent, limits = c(0, 0.02)) +
scale_x_continuous(label = percent, limits = c(0, 0.08))
```

Comment: `require(scales)`?

Comment: Is all your code within a chunk? Markdown does not have access to the global environment, only itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to `require(scales)` and after that specify "ticker" as I had not done that in my code chunk.

Both were suggested really quickly which is very helpful to me who is learning while writing my bachelor thesis. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Use `library()` instead of `require()`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to quote percent.

```
ggplot(d, aes(sd,meanret, color= ticker)) + 
geom_point(size=1) + geom_text(aes(label=names)) + 
ggtitle("Monthly Risk-Return Plot") + xlab("Volatility") +
ylab("Mean Return") + theme_bw() +
scale_y_continuous(label = "percent", limits = c(0, 0.02)) +
scale_x_continuous(label = "percent", limits = c(0, 0.08))
```

When not using quotes, ggplot is looking for an object named `percent` that should hold a string. Because of this, you could also do

```
p <- ggplot(...)
mylabel = "This is my label"
p + scale_x_continuous(label = "mylabel", limits = c(0, 0.08))
```